# Are new return objects created when mocks are called in Spock?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

When I try invoking the mock, we noticed it was returning a different object everytime.

```
List returnedList = []
Service service = Mock()
service.method() >> returnedList

println System.identityHashCode(service.method())
println System.identityHashCode(service.method())
println System.identityHashCode(service.method())
```

Output:

```
710903845
1709394654
759720212
```

Is there a way for it to just return the same object?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's very interesting behaviour. Can you provide a code of Service class. 
Such results can be explained if the method `Service#method()` is `final`

In non-final case the test bellow is green. I'm using spock 1.0-groovy2.4.

```
static class Service {
    List<String> method() {
        return ['a']
    }
}

def "mock should return the same object"() {
    given:
    List returnedList = []
    Service service = Mock()
    service.method() >> returnedList

    when:
    def res1 = System.identityHashCode(service.method())
    def res2 = System.identityHashCode(service.method())
    def res3 = System.identityHashCode(service.method())

    then:
    service.method().is(returnedList)
    res1 == res2
    res2 == res3
}
```